# why ng-click not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I write a directive to impl ng-disabled because i just can use angularjs which version is 1.1.5,it't not provide ng-disabled,so

```
tableApp.directive('myDisabled', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    myDisabled: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var test = scope.$eval(attrs.myDisabled);
    console.log(test);
    scope.$watch(attrs.myDisabled, function (test) {
      if (test) {
        element.attr();
      }
      else {
        element.attr('disabled', 'false');
      }
    });
  }
};
});
```

the html code:

```
<html ng-app="tableApp">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
      <input ng-model="page"/>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="previouspage()" my-disabled="page <=1">上一页</button>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

but why i click this button,it can't call the function `previouspage()`

this is my angularjs code

```
var tableApp = angular.module('tableApp', [], function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 
         'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
});

tableApp.directive('myDisabled', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    myDisabled: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var test = scope.$eval(attrs.myDisabled);
    console.log(test);
    scope.$watch(attrs.myDisabled, function (test) {
      if (test) {
        element.attr();
      }
      else {
        element.attr('disabled', 'false');
      }
    });
    $compile(attrs);
  }
};
});

tableApp.controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.page = 1;
$scope.getCr = function getCr(later) {
  var url = '/cms/copyright/find';
  var request = $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    params: {
      page_length: 25,
      start: ($scope.page - 1) * 25,
      s: ''
    }
  });

  request.then(function (data) {
    if (data.data.result == 'OK') {
      console.log(data.data);
      $scope.copyright = data.data;
      if (later != undefined) {
        later();
      }
    }
  });
};

$scope.nextpage = function nextpage() {
  $scope.page += 1;
  $scope.getCr();
};

$scope.onepage = function onepage() {
  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.getCr();
};

$scope.previouspage = function previouspage() {
  $scope.page -= 1;
  $scope.getCr();
};

$scope.setPos = function setPos(index, holder_id) {
  var pos = window.prompt("请输入排序位置", $scope.copyright.items[index].pos);
  console.log(pos);
  if (pos != null && pos != "" && parseInt(pos) > 0) {
    var a = 'holder_id=' + holder_id + '&pos=' + pos;
    $http.post('/cms/copyright/top', a).then(function (data) {
      data = data.data;
      if (data.result == 'OK') {
        $scope.getCr(function () {
          $scope.copyright.items[index].change = true;
        });
      } else {
        alert(data.result);
      }
    });
  }

  console.log($scope.copyright.items[index]);
};

$scope.getCr();
});
```

Comment: How do you declare `previouspage()` in your `controllers `scope`?

Comment: yes,i declare it in my controllers`    $scope.previouspage = function previouspage() {
      $scope.page -= 1;
      $scope.getCr();
    };`

Comment: Can you provide some more details from your markup or create an fiddle, please?

Comment: What is the initial value of $scope.page?

Comment: ok, i show my all angularjs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to `$scope`.

When you are explicitly creating an isolated scope in your directive (using scope: {}) you can't access parent scope directly. If you don't, there is no problem doing so.

So, in short, just change `ng-click="previouspage()"` to `ng-click="$parent.previouspage()"` inside your HTML template.

Related plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WRflPF
[image]

You could also refactor your directive's `link` function and remove unnecessary properties. So directive could be:

```
app.directive('myDisabled', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myDisabled: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('myDisabled', function (val) {
        element.attr('disabled', val);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: cool!but it is a new problem.why the page is bigger than 1 but the button is also disabled?

Comment: I refined my plunker a little, maybe it helps you figure it out? Button is disabled only when page <= 1. See refined directive in script.js (or in my answer above).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the directive `scope`. You try to access an `scope` variable from parent scope (your controllers scope)

If you disable the isolate `scope` for your directive it works

For example:

```
tableApp.directive('myDisabled', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    myDisabled: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var test = scope.$eval(attrs.myDisabled);
    console.log(test);
    scope.$watch(attrs.myDisabled, function (test) {
      if (test) {
        element.attr();
      }
      else {
        element.attr('disabled', 'false');
      }
    });
  }
};
});
```